# Videos feed from YouTube based on the import feeds systems drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, youtube-api, feed

How to import youtube videos from feeds with the help of Feeds Import and Feeds: Youtube parser module ? Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API V2 supports RSS and ATOM feeds. Here's an example RSS feed: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=rss, ATOM is the default format in V2, so the feed URL is: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2. For more information see https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol